# How do I abort PHP without any output?

Tags: php, apache

I'm writing a target script for an automated notification which does not need any return information. 
If using the exit then still the HTTP headers are (presumably) sent back. Is there any way for even less output? Something like "Connection closed by foreign host".

Apache+php module

Comment: maybe using die()? not sure about that though

Comment: THere is no sense in doing that, a lack of headers is always a issue and should never be 'implemented'. Anyhow, maybe unsetting all headers... die or exit will not prevent basic headers to be sent.

Comment: Instead of polling (really fast, presumably) and trying to return less data with each poll, why don't you implement long polling? I once did something like this in php, where my ajaxed script would sleep until it timed out, or it got a message via a global session I set up. It was actually pretty efficient, using minimal server resources.

Comment: If it doesn't need any return info, then just don't look at the return info?

Answer (score 0):

For a simple 301 redirect header, you can use something like this:

```
<?php
    header("Location: http://www.google.com");
    die("Connection closed by foreign host");
?>
```